# Is it possible to use Social Sign-in feature on custom login page?

Tags: onelogin

I have created a custom login page on my domain using Onelogin APIs that lets my customer to login to my portal. I am using onelogin as Single Sign in.

Onelogin offers social sign-in feature on their branded login page but my question is, can I implement social sign-in feature to my custom onelogin login page as well?

Comment: What language/framework/etc are you using? Are you attempting to use just Javascript/HTML or some other combination of things? A few more details are needed.

Comment: I've integrated OneLogin Login API in PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP then you can use below

[HybridAuth](https://hybridauth.github.io/) is an open source social sign on php library.

And you can refer other decent libraries as well

[Libraries](http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries)

Comment: Bhavesh - This is for OneLogin!

Comment: Yes, Kindly confirm whether the answer met your requirement or not.

Comment: Can you explain your answer please? How can I connect HybridAuth with custom OneLogin page?